# Given a CSV file, how do I delete the content between the 2nd and 3rd tabs of each row?

Tags: csv

I am using a mac and I have a CSV file delimited by tabs. I want to just remove all the content between the 2nd and 3rd tabs or replace it with something like "XXXX". Is there a command for this?

Comment: The quickest way would be using a text editor that allows vertical selection (sublime, text mate), but I'm guessing you want to do this from the command line, in which case sed is your friend

Comment: @spuder, vim can do vertical selection too, but in this case the fields may not be aligned. Can editors deal with that? A spreadsheet would be more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cut`:

```
cut --complement -f 2-3 <file>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try awk

```
awk '{$3="XXXXX"; print $0}' infile > newfile
```